# Questions about distributivity of dot product proof

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, proof-explanation, solution-verification

My textbook presented a proof of the distributivity of the dot product:

> [image]
>
> From the diagram, $\vert \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C} \vert \cos\theta_3 = \vert \mathbf{B} \vert \cos \theta_1 + \vert \mathbf{C} \vert \cos \theta_2$. Multiply by $\vert \mathbf{A} \vert$.
> $\vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C} \vert \cos \theta_3 = \vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{B} \vert \cos \theta_1 + \vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{C} \vert \cos \theta_2$.
> So: $\mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C}$ (Dot product is distributive)

I find this "proof" questionable. I'm struggling to come to terms with what the author did for this last part:

> $\vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C} \vert \cos \theta_3 = \vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{B} \vert \cos \theta_1 + \vert \mathbf{A} \vert \vert \mathbf{C} \vert \cos \theta_2$.
> So: $\mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C}$ (Dot product is distributive)

This doesn't even seem like it's *proving* distributivity; rather, it seems like it's just applying the very property that it's supposed to prove. Am I correct, or is this actually a valid proof? Can someone please help me understand the "proof" step here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is valid... sort of. There's a neglect of the obtuse case, but otherwise it's fine. The author is using the geometric definition:
$$v \cdot w = |v| |w| \cos(\theta)$$
where $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ is the angle between $v$ and $w$.

With that in mind, they have let $\theta_1$ be the angle between $A$ and $B$, $\theta_2$ be the angle between $A$ and $C$, and $\theta_3$ be the angle between $B + C$ and $A$. The distributive law states $A \cdot (B + C) = A \cdot B + A \cdot C$, or in other words,
$$|A| |B + C| \cos (\theta_3) = |A| |B| \cos(\theta_1) + |A| |C| \cos(\theta_2).$$
The above statement is what the author is trying to prove. They need to get a logical argument from a true statement that **ends** with the above equality, which is what they do. They begin with the observation that
$$|B| \cos(\theta_1) + |C| \cos(\theta_2) = |B + C| \cos(\theta_3)$$
which is evident from the picture (there's some missing geometry stuff here, about how rectangles have pairs of parallel sides that are the same length, etc, but the picture itself is clear).

From this true statement, they multiply both sides by $|A|$ to get another true equality. As it so happens, this equality is the one they needed to end up with.

So yes, the proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not convinced by your argument. From a proof perspective, it seems to me that the author is skipping steps and making implicit assumptions in those missing intermediate steps that invalidate the proof; in particular, by assuming the distributivity of the dot product, rather than proving it. Multiplying both sides of $\vert B + C \vert \cos (\theta_3) = \vert B \vert \cos(\theta_1) + \vert C \vert \cos(\theta_2)$ by $\vert A \vert$, we [...]

Comment: [...] get $\vert A \vert [\vert B + C \vert \cos (\theta_3)] = \vert A \vert [\vert B \vert \cos(\theta_1) + \vert C \vert \cos(\theta_2)]$. But we cannot yet assume this expression to be equal to $\vert A \vert \vert B + C \vert \cos (\theta_3) = \vert A \vert \vert B \vert \cos(\theta_1) + \vert A \vert \vert C \vert \cos(\theta_2)$; by doing so, one implicitly assumes that the dot product is indeed distributive, which is precisely what we are trying to prove. This is why my argument is that the author's proof is invalid: it seems to assume the very thing it's supposed to show.

Comment: The distributive property used in that step is that of real numbers. They're using the fact that $x(y + z) = xy + xz$ for $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R}$. In this case $x = |A|$, $y = |B| \cos(\theta_1)$ and $z = |C| \cos (\theta_2)$. The multiplication used there is **not the dot product**, but the usual product of real numbers. So, we are using the distribuitivity of real multiplication to prove the distribuitivity of dot products.

Comment: Ahh, yes!!! That makes sense. This is a commonly used proof strategy to prove the properties of, say, complex numbers (that is, using the properties of real numbers). But one thing I still am not sure of: Where does the dot product aspect of it come into play? It uses the distributivity property of the real numbers, but I don't see it then translating it into the dot product property itself. Perhaps I'm not seeing it because the dot product notation is left out? Not sure.

Comment: So, as I said previously, the geometric form of the dot product is being used. The *definition* of, say, $A \cdot B$ is the product of real numbers $|A| |B| \cos(\theta_1)$, since $\theta_1$ is defined to be the angle between the vectors $A$ and $B$. You might be used to the other definition of the dot product, i.e. $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = ac + bd$. It's easier to show the distributive property with this definition, but the geometry of the situation is arguably obscured, so the text has gone for a slightly trickier, but a lot more geometric option.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Thinking of it as $x(y + z) = xy + xz$ for $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R}$, and with $x = |A|$, $y = |B| \cos(\theta_1)$, and $z = |C| \cos (\theta_2)$ helps make things clear.

Comment: Glad I could help!